# How can I record demos of my gameplay?

Tags: recording

I remember seeing a lot of cool Counter Strike videos back in the day. How do you go about recording your gameplay (any game) into an easy to edit format? Do you need special software? How much does it cost?

Comment: I think this is more of a general computer question and as such belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: Not really, Fraps (below) is designed for recording 'in game 3D' play. Not everyday (2D) screen stuff.

Comment: for the source engine, you can also record demos using the "record" command. That's not a video format but Valve's own format which you can replay later and capture, to save any latency issues. It was also (and might still) be used extensively for PoV tests for cheating.

Comment: Fraps can record your desktop and thus games, if you play in window mode IF and WHEN you use Windows 7 due its Aerowhatchamacallit Desktop.

Comment: @badp What's FOSS?

Comment: @Grace Free, Open Source Software.

Comment: @badp I've noticed you often use acronyms that I either need to look up or someone has to have you define for them.  Maybe you could consider typing things out instead?

Comment: @strix LMGTFY :P

Comment: Woo for F O S S!

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/6801/what-is-the-best-software-for-desktop-recording)

Comment: What a sense was from *opensource*, if it's glitchy and still doesn't beat fraps in any measurement...

Comment: Should this be a community wiki?

Comment: For a better fragmovie making experience, I recommend record demos using the in-game console command `/record <name>` and then you record it with any of the programs mentioned in the answers.

Comment: And after your game (or once you stop the recording), you open fraps and play the demo to save it into a video format.

Comment: You can also use the Source Movie Editor for that I think @Fabián

Comment: The point is that you can take advantage of a record/replay function of the game and record the most relevant moment of the game you had.

Comment: You may use SME for Source-made games only. As for many other games that doesn't have this kind of movie-making program, they at least have record/replay functions, either included or as a separated program.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**[Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/)** is the most popular tool for recording in game videos.

*Update:* [dxTory](http://exkode.com/dxtory-features-en.html) seems to be stealing a lot of Frap's userbase now, and according to [Totalbiscuit](http://www.youtube.com/user/TotalHalibut) suffers less frame drops.

> Fraps is a universal Windows
>   application that can be used with
>   games using DirectX or OpenGL graphic
>   technology.  In its current form Fraps
>   performs many tasks and can best be
>   described as:
>
> Benchmarking Software - Show how many
>   Frames Per Second (FPS) you are
>   getting in a corner of your screen. 
>   Perform custom benchmarks and measure
>   the frame rate between any two points.
>   Save the statistics out to disk and
>   use them for your own reviews and
>   applications.
>
> Screen Capture Software - Take a
>   screenshot with the press of a key! 
>   There's no need to paste into a paint
>   program every time you want a new
>   shot.  Your screen captures are
>   automatically named and timestamped.
>
> Realtime Video Capture Software - Have
>   you ever wanted to record video while
>   playing your favourite game?  Come
>   join the Machinima revolution!  Throw
>   away the VCR, forget about using a DV
>   cam, game recording has never been
>   this easy!  Fraps can capture audio
>   and video up to 2560x1600 with custom
>   frame rates from 10 to 120 frames per
>   second!
>
> All movies are recorded in outstanding
>   quality.  If you have Windows Media
>   Player please sample some of the
>   movies captured with Fraps below:

Comment: If it costs money please specify that

Comment: For windows only.

Comment: Yes it currently cost $37 for lifetime licence

Comment: And well worth the money, in my opinion, even though I'm looking for alternatives, for no specific reasons.

Comment: Fraps is okay. You can record 30 seconds free, if you need to record more you need to buy it @MarmouCorp

Comment: I've used FRAPS and find that on my high-spec PC it reduces game performance during recording. This reduction is slight, but enough of a reduction on split-second-reactions-are-vital games (such as Call of Duty games) to hurt your success in the game.

Comment: At $37 for a lifetime it's dirt cheap. I never saw a reason to go looking for anything else considering how good it is.

Comment: When using fraps it's recommended to save to another hard drive or hard drive partition than where either windows or your game is installed. Due to the constant writing to disk, it will slow down a lot for other things.

Comment: I bought fraps over 10 years ago, and my old email and password still work to download the latest version, so when they say "lifetime", they mean it.

Comment: so dxTory gives better framerate for users?

Comment: It might be worth updating this answer now windows 10 is out

Answer (score 30):

[**TAKSI**](http://taksi.sourceforge.net/) (open source; Windows only)

> TAKSI: Video capture/Screen capture for 3D graphics
>
> Taksi is a utility that allows you to
>   take screenshots and record video
>   clips of your favourite games and
>   other 3D-graphics applications.
>   Inspired by Fraps (www.fraps.com),
>   Taksi aims to provide an *open
>   source* alternative to that great
>   tool.

Despite the webpage claims the latest stable release has been done in 2006, the project does not seem completely abandoned. [Development version 0.7.7.9](http://sourceforge.net/projects/taksi/files/development/taksi-0.7.7.9-dev/taksi-0.7.7.9-dev.msi/download) has been released in July 2010.

Comment: I did a few tests on this and it does take a pretty significant hit on the system. That is to be expected in early versions though. It could be promising in the future

Comment: it still seems to be active, last submission yesterday and four per month in april and march: http://sourceforge.net/projects/taksi/develop

Comment: By FOSS we of course mean "software I don't have to pay for", rather than giving a crap about whether you plan to clone the repository, learn the innards of screen capture systems in C++ and submit patches to improve on it.

Answer (score 26):

**[VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)**  (open source, windows, linux & os x)
I have used VLC to record a video on windows. I have not tried this on linux or os x.

Launch the game of your choosing in **windowed fullscreen** mode.

Start up VLC.

[image: VLC]

On the "Media" menu select "Convert / Save..." (CTRL-R)

The "Open Media" dialog will appear, select the "Capture Device" tab

[image: Capture Device]

Change the capture mode to "Desktop".

Adjust the desired frame rate for capture, I set it to 30.00 f/s.

Click on the "Convert /Save" button.

The "Convert" dialog will appear.

[image: Convert]

Click the "Browse" button to find place to save the video and give it a name.

I use "capture.asf" as a filename

Select the profile you want to use. I have found that "Video WMV + WMA (ASF)" give the best results for me.

Press the "Start" button.

Activate the game and play for a bit, VLC will make a recording, when you want to stop recording activate VLC and press the stop button, then close it down.

The ASF format I use produces very large files, for a 2560 x 1600 display it takes about 1GB for 3 minutes of video. You can experiement with different encodings if you like but I had problems with the others so decided to use ASF, I imagine I can convert it to something smaller later.

Comment: I did not know VLC could do that! TIL, and +1.

Answer (score 21):

### [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) (Free, open source, Windows / Mac / Linux)

It allows you to capture the screen, specific windows, games (using hooks) and even external sources (e.g. video capture card capturing consoles). You can output the captured video to a local file.

> OBS Studio (formerly known as OBS Multiplatform) is a complete rewrite of the original OBS from the ground up, with the main goals being multiplatform support, a more thorough feature set, and a much more powerful API. While still in its early stages, releases are currently available for Windows, Mac and Linux.
>
> OBS Studio will eventually support many of the advanced requested features not present in the original OBS, such as multiple stream outputs and scene previewing, the latter of which is now available in the current release.

---

(Older version) [Open Broadcaster Software](http://obsproject.com) (Free, open source, Windows x86 and x64 / Mac)

It allows you to capture the screen, specific windows, games (using hooks) and even external sources (e.g. video capture card capturing consoles). You can output the captured video to a local file.

Though it has another more important use: it can stream the captured video on the Internet. That's why the program can actually mix multiple input video source into one output.

One thing to note that it does not show an fps counter like Fraps.

> Open Broadcaster Software is free and open source software for recording and live streaming. Source code is available to everyone to contribute and improve. Both 32 and 64 bit versions are available and it's absolutely free!

Comment: The fact it is aimed at streaming (but also supports recording) means that it supports [adjusting audio levels](http://youtu.be/bSmf_MkR0Io) (two sliders: one for the mic, another for the game/desktop), which is VERY useful. In addition, you can choose the video resolution and quality. Finally, it also supports a [replay buffer](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-use-the-replay-buffer.103/), where it continuously record the last "x" seconds of gameplay, and upon pressing a shortcut it will write those to the disk.

Answer (score 9):

Chris S probably gave [what will become the most popular and accepted answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-record-demos-of-my-gameplay/396#396). Still, I think **[wegame.com](http://www.wegame.com/)** (Windows only) should get a mention.  It allows you to record nearly any game with their client and upload it to their site.  It's also free.  Unfotunately, I don't think you can do much in terms of editing the video.

Comment: What should also be mentioned is that wegame client uses far less resources and is far less demanding than Fraps is at the cost of huge quality loss.

YouTube already decreases your video's quality by re-encoding the whole footage, so it pays to record in very high quality, then encode with as little quality loss as possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, Wegame is defunct.

Answer (score 7):

**[Dxtory](http://dxtory.com/home-en.html)** (Windows only) is worth a mention as well.

It's 3,600 JPY (~US$40), but there is a free demo.

> Dxtory is a movie capture tool only for DirextX/OpenGL application.
>   In order to acquire data from Surface Memory directly, It operates very much at high speed.
>   Arbitrary cropping and free scaling are supported by hardware.

Its main selling point is that it uses multiple hard drives for its operation, therefore avoiding the main bottleneck of video capture, which is recording speed*.

(*) I've tested this using 4 HDDs (all different), and the performance hit is noticeably lower than other similar software.

Answer (score 6):

While [**Fraps**](http://www.fraps.com/) is the best solution for recording 3D-accelerated games and applications (and that includes 2D games that use your 3D videocard), it can't record your desktop or your browser.

For general-purpose desktop recording, I recommend [**CamStudio**](http://camstudio.org/), which is free and open source. It can be used to record things that Fraps usually can't (for instance, in-browser games and some simple 2D games that don't use DirectX), as well as general game-related videos (e.g. tutorials, or a game launcher screen).

For simple video editing and conversion (for instance, before uploading to YouTube), I recommend [**VirtualDub**](http://www.virtualdub.org/), which is also free and open source.

Comment: On Windows Vista and Windows 7, Fraps can in fact record your desktop.

Comment: But only when Aero is enabled, right? Or is it a new feature of Fraps?

Comment: The second part of your first sentence is incorrect. FRAPS can record the desktop (without mouse cursor) as of Vista.

Comment: CamStudio is responsible for so many crappy videos on youtube it's not even funny.

Comment: @badp It's because they change the quality to so low and don't use the lossless video codec probably. If used correctly, CamStudio is a good recorder.

Answer (score 6):

I made some tutorial back then when I was beginning recording my gameplay for [my YouTube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/Mamboi)

- [Fraps & VirtualDub: How to save disk space and enjoy good quality, small file size HD video clips](http://www.donsalva.com/fraps-virtualdub-save-disk-space-good-quality-small-filesize/)
- [VirtualDub 720p HD settings for YouTube! [Good quality, small file size]](http://www.donsalva.com/virtualdub-720p-hd-settings-youtube/)
- [How to set up your computer for gameplay recording](http://www.donsalva.com/how-to-set-up-your-computer-for-pc-game-play-recording/)

Answer (score 6):

### [Xfire - Gaming Simplified](http://www.xfire.com/)

Xfire is free, and in some ways it is better for recording games than other tools.

You can set a hotkey to quickly start recording the game that is currently active window. You are shown a small status bar inside the game with current length of the video and disk space it takes (the bar isn't shown in the video.)

Xfire can't do general screen recording, it is only for games. It records games in both fullscreen and windowed modes.

Result video is a high quality .avi file with resolution the same as the game window's client size, or half-size (depends on what you choose).

The bad thing about Xfire is that it not only does video records... Well, see for yourself at their [website](http://www.xfire.com/)

For Windows only.

Comment: I tried xfire but i could not get it done. Which is strange because i always succeed in getting things done on my PC. Maybe it was more simpler then i figured back then but i abandoned it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using hypercam 2 in combination with virtualdub to produce very high quality gameplay footage you can see here:

Hypercam 2 is much more versatile then FRAPS which only allows you to record DirectX games on full screen. It also allows you to compress your recordings on the fly so you do not end up with those huge files. Sometimes i even manage to compress my video's on the fly good enough to upload them at once. I have a Phenom II X4 with a GeForce 460 GTX which is pretty dated nowadays.

Things you need, all free:

Hypercam 2 - for recording. http://download.cnet.com/HyperCam/3000-13633_4-10004511.html

X264 VFW codec - for video compressing. http://sourceforge.net/projects/x264vfw/

Lame mp3 - for audio compressing. (i got mine in a pack) http://www.free-codecs.com/download/K_lite_codec_pack.htm

virtualdub - for editing. http://virtualdub.sourceforge.net/

**Hypercam:**
On the screen area tab you can specify the area you want to record. For full screen you just put the resolution the game is running and the start x,y will be just 0. If you want to record a single window you have the option to select that window directly using the hypercam ui.

The next tab is just for setting up your hotkeys, i use CTRL-INSERT to start and stop recording.

On the AVI file tab you specify the output file on the top. You have the option to add a sequential number to the files so you do not overwrite your previous recording and they get a logic number behind the name you give (unlike fraps). You can also specifie the framerate and playback speed, doubling the playback speed will speed up the video 2 times.

For compressing on the fly i use 15 frames per second which is really hard to notice if you are watching. I always leave the cursor capturing on 1 and keyframes on every 100 frames. Then you choose the video compressor, picking no compression will create huge files so i always advice to pick X264 and just choose a inexpensive compression method. When compressing on the fly always choose the ultrafast compressing method in the X264 UI.

The rest speaks for itself, at options you can choose to record the cursor or not.

**Virtualdub:**
Here you edit your video and compress it further if you need too. You can just drag in or open a avi you created. If you picked subsequential numbering and have multiple video's you can choose append avi segment, just pick the first video in line and it will recognize the numbering.

Under video you find filters where you can crop your video or add black TV bars to it. There are also some special effects to choose from. Re sizing your video is also possible but the quality deteriorates fast.

At video->compression you can select a compression. Now you can opt for a slower compression method and play with the bit rate to see what works for you. If you have slow gameplay and dull colors you can get away with a lot more then fast gameplay with vibrant colors.

In the audio->compression section you can pick the lame mp3 codec to compress the audio, you don't need much audio quality most of the time i just pick a 96kb rate.

Now you can save the new avi under files and it will compress it for you. You can see the predicted file size, which is pretty accurate after running for a minute. My advice is to play around with the option a lot.

Here is a video guide of me:

Answer (score 4):

[Simple Screen Recorder](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/) is a free and open source screencasting program for linux.

It supports recording OpenGL windows directly (as well as recording the screen normally), which is good for games where performance is critical.

It has many other features and is simple to use.

From [their website](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/):

> ## Features
>
> - Graphical user interface (Qt-based).
> - Faster than VLC and ffmpeg/avconv.
> - Records the entire screen or part of it, or records OpenGL applications directly (similar to Fraps on Windows).
> - Synchronizes audio and video properly (a common issue with VLC and ffmpeg/avconv).
> - Reduces the video frame rate if your computer is too slow (rather than using up all your RAM like VLC does).
> - Fully multithreaded: small delays in any of the components will never block the other components, resulting is smoother video and
>   better performance on computers with multiple processors.
> - Pause and resume recording at any time (either by clicking a button or by pressing a hotkey).
> - Shows statistics during recording (file size, bit rate, total recording time, actual frame rate, ...).
> - Can show a preview during recording, so you don't waste time recording something only to figure out afterwards that some setting
>   was wrong.
> - Uses libav/ffmpeg libraries for encoding, so it supports many different codecs and file formats (adding more is trivial).
> - Can also do live streaming (experimental).
> - Sensible default settings: no need to change anything if you don't want to.
> - Tooltips for almost everything: no need to read the documentation to find out what something does.

Answer (score 3):

All other anwsers are about screen-recording software. It's important to notice, though, that the first step of creating your demo should be using the game built-in demo recording mechanism, whenether available. The *second* step is to record the playback of that demo using Fraps-like program. Why is that?

- For many players, the framerate drops caused by screen recording software like Fraps is unacceptable
- You can record on other video settings than you generally use for gameplay
- You can record only parts of your demo, saving disk space

Answer (score 3):

[Loilo Game recorder](http://loilo.tv/us/product/game_recorder)

Features:

- Free
- No watermark (Unless you use bundled Video editing software trial but its no issues to save vidoes and import into another Editor like [Lightworks](http://www.lwks.com/) (offers free version with upgrade to pro))
- Website claims better performance then Dxtory, BandiCamm, and Fraps
- No recording timelimit

To Use:

- Download the software
- Install the software
- [image: List item]
- Above picture right off website

Comment: Just recommending a product, without providing instructions on how to use it to achieve the goal being attempted, isn't very useful at all.

Comment: Updated with screen shot from website showing how to use this tool.

Answer (score 3):

[Shadowplay](http://www.geforce.co.uk/geforce-experience/shadowplay)

Shadowplay is free software which only requires you to have a supported nVidia graphics card.

It records video playback directly from the GPU and saves it to mp4 files on a specified location.

Answer (score 1):

**[Smartpixel](http://www.smartpixel.com)** is the best game screen recorder available for all different platform like **Windows,Android and IOS**.

**Step 1**. Adjust game recording settings. Take WOW for example. When I loading in the game and click Smartpixel Screen/Game button, it will be like this.
**Step 2**. Game video recording. After the recording settings done, we can come back the Smartpixel floating window, select erea mode, full screen mode or PIP mode, if we want to record partly game screen, we might need to manually adjust the 4 red coordinates on the game screen.
**Step 3**. Game video editing. Before upload to YouTube, you might need to modify the game videos, cut the unwantted part, merge several video clips together, add some background music, add some transitions, subtitles etc. All this can be done with Smartpixel software, After that you can upload the game videos to YouTube.
**Here is the youtube tutorial:**
The basics of [how to use smartpixel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9OhagYnjkc)!