# Is it possible to save a replay in Burnout Paradise?

Tags: pc, burnout-paradise

Burnout Paradise is very spectacular and sometimes after some crazy jump or incident I would like to save a replay of the action.

Is it possible to save a replay in Burnout Paradise?

Comment: See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-record-demos-of-my-gameplay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were talks about a DLC that would add this functionality last year. But later on it was stated that [it will not be added.](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/933706-burnout-paradise/47952706) So your best bet is through FRAPS or other capturing mechanic.

Comment: That's a pity :( I don't want to register all my sessions with external recorder. In any case thanks for the info.