# What can I do to record videos of me gaming for free?

Tags: recording

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I record demos of my gameplay?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-record-demos-of-my-gameplay)

I have looked at a few choices:

- I liked **Fraps**, but it's $37 for the full version.
- **dxtory** was good but the video quality wasn't clear.
- I wasn't able to use **virtualdub** because i did not have the hardware to go with it.
- **Camstudio** is only for windows xp.

My question is, is there a free screen recorder that has no limit on how long a video is that can also record audio and have a clear video quality? The quality doesn't have to be HD, but not horrible either.

Comment: you want [Super User](http://www.superuser.com "click me"), not gaming.

Comment: I would mention Jing, but I'm not sure it has the capability to record from DirectX, plus it's limited to 5 minute videos.

Comment: *"camstudio is only for windows xp"* - and vista/7... so what OS exactly are you looking for?  Linux?  Mac?  Also, what does your last sentence mean?

Comment: As usual I'm in the minority in thinking this is a perfectly legitimate question here, apparently.

Comment: @badp he's asking for recording software.  While you can use that for games, it isn't really about games, playing games, or gaming in general. This is really a question about using your computer and it seems to me the best place for that is SU.

Comment: Nick, I've placed a bounty for what you're asking for [on this very similar question.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-record-demos-of-my-gameplay)