# How can I record gameplay without a dip in framerate?

Tags: recording

I use `Fraps` when recording my gameplays but it chops off like 5-9 FPS and makes the recorded video laggy. Is there any tool I can use to record gameplay without a resulting loss of ***much*** FPS?

Added Bounty.

Comment: sorry, you may claim otherwise, but this question _is_ a de facto duplicate of [How can I record demos of my gameplay?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-record-demos-of-my-gameplay) - however, your additional requirement "without loss of FPS" leads to the interesting [hardware solution](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34539/how-can-i-record-gameplay-without-a-dip-in-framerate/34545#34545), which would also be a valid answer there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there ways of recording your game without using the game-playing PC's resources?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8393/are-there-ways-of-recording-your-game-without-using-the-game-playing-pcs-resour)