# Free Screen Recorder for Games?

Tags: recording

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I record demos of my gameplay?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-record-demos-of-my-gameplay)

Are there any free screen recorder for games? Camtasia Studio isn't that well optimised and FRAPs is a bit too expensive.

Comment: What you're looking for is http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-record-demos-of-my-gameplay/8299#8299

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the trial (free) version of FRAPs is able to do screen capture pretty well. I know I used it for a project a couple of years ago - I think that functionality is still free.