# How can I record a fullscreen game?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I record demos of my gameplay?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-record-demos-of-my-gameplay)

I've been playing Portal 2 on PC, and apparently I can only play it on fullscreen.
I use Camtasia, and I wanted to record something, but all I get is a black screen (but the audio is recorded well). So how can I record the game video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/) is made for games, works well for most games, even old ones. It's not free but i believe there is a tryout version

Comment: And the quality is awesome...

Answer (score 1):

[**TAKSI: Video capture/Screen capture for 3D graphics**](http://taksi.sourceforge.net/)

> Taksi is a utility that allows you to
>   take screenshots and record video
>   clips of your favourite games and
>   other 3D-graphics applications.
>   Inspired by Fraps (www.fraps.com),
>   Taksi aims to provide an **open
>   source** alternative to that great
>   tool.

Despite the webpage claims the latest stable release has been done in 2006, the project does not seem completely abandoned. [Development version 0.7.7.9](http://sourceforge.net/projects/taksi/files/development/taksi-0.7.7.9-dev/taksi-0.7.7.9-dev.msi/download) has been released in July 2010.

Comment: I'm posting my answer on gaming.SE also here in case the question is not closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

above solutions might be better for your specific case, but for completeness sake here is a completely different solution to record full screen applications:

using virtual pc, virtual box, vm ware or similar, run the application on the guest system (virtual system) and the recording software on the host system (your "real" os). This will record everything, including things that are otherwise difficult to record like full screen console, windows login screen, etc.

Using the same principle you can record anything running in a remote desktop session on a 2nd pc.

I have used both methods successfully before but they don't work with every application.