# What's the best program to use to record Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, recording

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I record demos of my gameplay?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-record-demos-of-my-gameplay)

I want to [record myself playing Minecraft](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1MjyzBgYY8&playnext=1&list=PL996E04E565AA34E9), what program should I use?

Comment: FRAPs is the only game-recording software I know of...

Comment: @RavenDreamer There are alternatives, like Taksi.