# How does one capture gameplay video on PC?

Tags: pc, recording

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I record demos of my gameplay?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-record-demos-of-my-gameplay)

How does one capture gameplay video on PC?

I am currently playing Skyrim, how can I capture the video of my character?

Do I need new hardware to capture my gameplay video?

Comment: It looks like half a question and half a guild/clan application :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need new hardware, just software. There are plenty of free screen capturing softwares on the web. Try sorting through here : http://techie-buzz.com/softwares/top-free-screen-recorders-to-record-your-screen-activities.html . Should be a good start.