# How should I record high-quality video game footage?

Tags: recording

How should I record **high-quality** video game footage off consoles? I am interested in PC and mobile platform recording too. And Secondarily, how can I edit the footage professionally for YouTube trailers and gameplay videos?

P.S. for amateur level recording, please see [How can I record demos of my gameplay?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-record-demos-of-my-gameplay).

## Why:

This is primarily for professional trailers and footage from our indie game studio (i.e., http://youtube.com/xonagames), but also for posting YouTube videos of personal gameplay accomplishments (i.e., http://youtube.com/matthewdoucette).

## Current setup:

- Blackmagic Intensity Pro capture card
- Dell Precision T3400 workstation
- four 7,200 RPM hard drive RAID-0 array

  - simulates a single 28,800 RPM hard drive
  - Blackmagic recommends a 10..15 hard drive RAID-0 array, with a minimum requirement of a four hard drives
- Recording in 720p JPEG compression (5:1 file size compression compared to raw) <-- this is as high as I can go in compression and I need at least 720p resolution to maintain professional quality.
- Windows Vista (Windows 7 soon)
- edit raw output capture files in VirtualDub
- final edit in Windows Movie Maker (I know...)

This is a system we purchased and setup for professionally recording footage of our games. It needs improvement. I also use it to record personal video game play and would like to do this more. The inconvenience of it all is what stops me.

## Example output of current setup:

Here's an example trailer of our own video game, produced with this system:

If you have a good eye, or even not, you can see the swap fields problem on all the game play footage. I know the solution, but it requires too much meddling with VirtualDub to "fix" the huge raw output files from the Intensity Pro. In the trailer above, I simply forgot to do this and ran out of time to fix it. This trailer took about a day's work from start to end. Too much time for indie developers without time.

But, there's pros too. Here's example quality achieved by this setup, courtesy of Forza 3:

Amazing quality. Please note, which the very informed of you will already realize, that the above Forza 3 footage is from Forza 3's replay mode, which actually plays at 30 fps, not 60 fps, and it *blurs* the screen with motion blur effects. This is why it translates to the 30 fps (I think) of YouTube better than 60 fps gameplay with every second frame cut out. I want software that does this for me from my 60 fps footage, using every two frames (or more) together to produce a lower frame rate with proper motion blur.

## Problems with current setup:

Even with a four hard drive RAID-0 array, it still skips frames. A single skipped frame is not so bad, but when they add up it takes the video out of synch from the audio which is not skipped. Imagine separate video and audio buffers each being filled independently, but not equally whenever there is not information to fill it, which is what happens when the hard drive is too slow for a moment and skips recording the frame. You can see this effect at the end of this video, slightly, when you watch and listen to the "ting" of breaking the gates (Geometry Wars 2)...

...and this is only after 3 minutes. Imagine how far the audio/video synch would be after an hour. (The reason the video is ahead of the audio, and not vice-versa, is perhaps at first unintuitive depending how you think about it. I'll clear up the confusion: The video buffer is not filled as "high" as the audio buffer due to all the skipped video frames. Now imagine the final video frame, where there is extra audio to spare topping off the more filled audio buffer. Necessarily, the video is matched with audio from the "past". So when the player breaks a gate in Geometry Wars 2, you see the gate breaking and the audio of the gate breaking has yet to come. So upon replay the video happens first.)

Inconvenience #1: Because of the above skip frame problem, I have to take video in small chunks. A level at a time. I'd rather record for hours and forget I'm even recording, when playing games.

Inconvenience #2: Nothing on the computer can be loaded or in focus while the video is being recorded, which is Blackmagic's way of making sure they have full power of the computer to not skip frames. Not a flaw, but just inconvenient to have the PC unusable.

Swapped fields (think every two scan lines are swapped), which require editing in VirtualDub for importing into Windows Movie Maker.

What I would like to do is record for hours, preferably at 720p or 1080p at 60 fps or 30 fps blurred from 60 fps input.

## Bonus points

You'll get bonus points (not really) if you can help with any of the following:

Answer the same question for recording off of PC's (with an HDMI output in my card, I think I can use the same solution as a console) and mobile platforms.

Suggest *anything*  that helps me have a better video recording setup. Including operating system (even though I'll be unlikely to change), hardware (HD PVRs maybe?), and software. Including anything cost-effective. We certainly do not have an unlimited budget, but have a need for professional video capturing.

Preservation of the 60 frames per second input, in the lower (30?) frames per second output, while keeping in mind whatever YouTube does for processing as well. For example, if the final YouTube video is only 30 fps, it's smoother to *not* drop every second frame but instead incorporate all the frames into a more blurry, but more information packed, 30 fps. This is why videos captured on 30 fps handheld cameras from our 60 fps games look smooth, as they do this maintaining of all frames' information inherently. Here's an example of my 30 fps camera recording my 60fps game, where you can feel the smoothness compared to other videos of the same game...

...you can see in the video above, especially when pausing it, that each frame contains more than one frame (of the original 60 fps frames) of information. THis video may only be 20 fps, as I can tell from the larger bosses that there are three distinct explosion rings when I know the game (at least at the time of the recording) only had one. All of this makes for a much smoother viewing which also more accurately portrays what you would see in real life.

Lot of stuff here. Lots of thoughts and rambling. Edit this question for clarity if you will. Any and all help is appreciated. (Note: I have posted links not for spam, but to be informative. Remove if need be, as well as this message.)

Comment: For anyone looking for a more amateur-level recording, see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-record-demos-of-my-gameplay

Comment: @Oak, thank you for that edit. Any way to fix the double underscore in youtube url bug? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClxTi__1F0s will not post as you can see at the bottom.

Comment: +1 well structured, comprehensive question - I wish I could help you, but I'm afraid I don't know enough about the subject at hand.  I am interested in the answers you get though.

Comment: Thank you. I've been wondering for years on this. HD PVRs may be my answer. I'm curious as to their quality and then I have to address how to edit those captures.

Comment: @MatthewDoucette fixed; also reported it on http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3969/double-underscore-messes-up-youtube-embedding

Comment: Why not design your graphics engine so that you can enable an option which spits out a video stream? Okay, that sounds harder than it is: Just so long as your code is capable of simply waiting long enough for a screen to be written to disk (easier than it sounds! Depending on implementation you may not need to do a thing), it won't be necessary to use insane storage hardware just to cope with keeping up with the video output. `glReadPixels` as a starting point, for example.

Comment: @Oak, how did you fix it? And thanks.

Comment: @StevenLu, we are running this on Xbox's at the moment, plus even if we ran our PC versions there are difficulties will outputting audio as well as such an immense amount of information fast enough to disc, as well as post processing of the images and audio we do output to create them into movies, etc. Also, a solution not dependent on this would allow me to record other people's games. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: @MatthewDoucette it's a bug when parsing "naked" URLs, it doesn't exist when you use HTML or specific markdown syntax. See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100887/141361) to see how to use the syntax. Also you can check [this post's revision history](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/50522/revisions) to see my changes.

Comment: you can fix the desync from skipped frames (I think) by inserting frames where they were skipped in post so the amount of frames stay proper compared to the sound

Comment: @ratchetfreak, how would I do this easily so it's not a tedious process? If there was an automated feature in VirtualDub or something that did it, it would be great.

Comment: is there a log of skipped frames? you could create a program to do so (or have one made)

Comment: Can you assume the frame drops occur uniformly throughout? Then you can just "stretch" the video or sound so that they are synched at the beginning and at the end during video editing (using anything you want as references) then just check at a few points in the middle to see if it's more or less correct.

Comment: @ratchetfreak, there is no log of skipped frames. And consider that the cost of time is more important to me than the cost of money. I want a solution that just works without needless fiddling.

Comment: @StevenLu, you could assume the frames are dropped uniformly, I believe, even though they are not. It depends on the frame I think and how close the computer is to dropping it. But like I said I want a better solution than this if possible. But I appreciate you bringing this up. I may have to make do with just such a solution.

Comment: Do I need more rep to set a bounty on this question?

Comment: @MatthewDoucette At least 2 days need to pass before you can set a bounty. Also, what console/framework are you developing on? Is this an XNA game?

Comment: @Ktash, all of our games so far have been XNA and HTML5/JavaScript, and soon we will adopt more cross-platform solutions. but this question was assuming console based gaming. I will adjust the question. Thank you for highlighting this omission.

Answer (score 1):

So, [this tutorial](http://jacobsmalls.hubpages.com/hub/Guides-to-Recording-Xbox-360-Gameplay-to-Desktop-or-Laptop) has a review of recording devices, including ones that support HD recording. It does note the following

> I WILL BE LISTING SOME HD COMPATIBLE RECORDING DEVICES that enable you to record in standard and play in High Def simultaneously later in this article. However the prices can vary dramatically on these devices. There is only one somewhat affordable external device that allows true HD capture and that is the Hauppauge HD PVR and it is listed below.

It also says

> As far as I know there are no affordable external devices that record 1080p or from an HDMI cable. The Hauppauge will do HD but it will only record in 720p or 1080i.

Mind you, this guide was posted *3 years ago* so there is no guarantee that the devices haven't improved since then, but this seems to be a very complete guide.

Honestly, I think you're going to find better support on the [GameDev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) side of things. A lot of players record their videos (especially those in [MLG](http://www.majorleaguegaming.com/)) but a lot of the times they won't care about audio syncing, or perfect framerates. You can take a look at [this guide over at the MLG forums](http://forums.majorleaguegaming.com/topic/28497-video-production-guide/), but a lot of their focus is on cheap rather than quality.

Comment: thank you for this. Can I cross post to GameDev?

Comment: @MatthewDoucette You can flag a moderator for your question and ask them to move it if you'd like. Cross posting as in posting it in both and sharing the response, etc. I don't think is really possible (but I don't know that for sure)

Answer (score 0):

I really think that if you brought up your concerns with the game engine people, the issue of capturing video output from a game will not require ANY type of hardware in addition to what the game runs on, let alone specialized incredibly expensive hardware like what you describe. Also this opens up the possibility of "enhancing" the output because you can combine multiple frames into a single one that goes in the final video, which will help it look much smoother.

The degree of difficulty involved in modifying a game to produce video output will vary. It could be extremely simple, by dumping the pixels from the screen buffer at every frame, or it could be quite difficult if the behavior of the game depends on the time taken to render. This is because the additional time it takes to copy the framebuffer data will be appended to the time it takes to render. It might simply make the game run slower (which is quite manageable as it should make a game easier to play, in general) or it might make the game uncontrollable and unresponsive, if the actual time difference between frames was used to determine parameters to update the game. Of course this all depends on the nuts and bolts of how the game is designed.

Now I'll point out that this type of approach wouldn't help you capture a video of Forza 3 gameplay at all.

Comment: The only reason I do not like this answer is because of the cost (of time). What I want, and perhaps I should have made this more clear in my question, is that I want something that works but works effortlessly as possible.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't done typing, and sent that by accident. There is also the cost of post processing the output. I'm not sure if some frameworks allow us to output the audio as well. Plus how can we do this on console systems which the frameworks generally lock us away from doing anything so extreme such as writing huge amounts of data.

Comment: Also, we *are* the "engine people". These games are built 100% in house.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the console development process and what tools are available. The system you already have is pretty much about as good as you can get for capturing output of games that are running, without modifying them. The sheer amount of data that is produced, and not being able to slow it down during capture generally rules out cheap solutions. Maybe you can get by with a SATA3 SSD though. My solution doesn't address sound either, like you pointed out. But as for fixing the slight desynchronization of sound due to frame drops, can't you fix that during video editing fairly easily?

Comment: Does that capture card have any encoding capabilities? That would greatly reduce the load on your storage solution if you could skip saving the uncompressed raw data.

Comment: I don't think I can fix the desynching of audio/video easily. But if you know of a solution, let me know. I'd rather not have to mess with it at all. Cost of time is more important to me than cost of money. And my Blackmagic Intensity Pro in its most compress format (JPEG that's 5:1) is when I can get away with having four hard drives just barely. I cannot go any further unfortunately.

Comment: What about lowering the resolution? Though it's true I'd certainly want my game trailer to be in at least 720p resolution. That's unfortunate that the capture card doesn't handle audio. If it spits out a stream of single frame images, you should be able to parse the timestamps and analyze them to figure out when frames got dropped. This will be a lot of work for marginal improvement over manual sync adjustment. Since this type of thing puts out so much data I wonder if there is software that can let you save your data to RAM first? It will limit your record time but you can get 32/64GB of RAM.

Comment: I am already doing it at 720p and cannot go lower as it would come of as very amateur. I'll add this in the question that I have already lowered it from 1080 to 720. (In fact our games run, so far, natively in 720p). And the capture card handles audio, so I'm not sure what you were getting at there. The capture card works perfectly with a fast enough hard drive RAID-0 array actually. I just cannot extend my RAID-0 array without significant cost. Without the skips, I would basically be fine. The next step would be better software solutions to producing trailers.

Comment: also limiting my recording time is no solution for me. That's very inconvenient to have to start and stop recording over and over, especially for personal game recording. Starting over and over actually is what I do while recording trailer footage though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can unfocus the Blackmagic software and continue recording, by changing an option in the settings, thus you can use your computer while recording.

Comment: thanks for letting me know about this. It uses so much resources that it basically will not help me. Now I'm feeling that a better solution, if it works, would be a HD PVR that is separate from the computer, something that could run for hours.