# How to record World of Warcraft online gameplay and replay it?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am new to WoW game and would like to know,
Is there any facility like DOTA2 and League of Legends to record gameplay and replay again in game without using any 3rd party tools?

Comment: There is no way. If you just want to make a video see this: [How can I record demos of my gameplay?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-record-demos-of-my-gameplay)

Comment: Ofcourse, third party means anything apart from the client, and it is likely you say no 3rd party as you do not wish to download more software. As another answer states, windows 10 has this feature built in, aswell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no in-game way to save footage and replay it.

Most players that are interested in "replay" are just interested in damage done, damage taken, and healing stats.  There are many in-game addons, known as damage meters, which can provide these numbers.  Examples are Skada, Recount, Mr Robot.

Comment: Slight clarification: You can use any number of video capture to save your experience into a movie file, but there's no available tools to record and play-back the location data of every entity and player. (Compared to Starcraft's replay system or Heroes of the Storm replay)

Comment: Ah, didn't catch that part. :( apologies!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your operating system you have different choices, Mac has an in game recording feature that can be used. On Windows, although third party, the closest you can get to this would be using something like ShadowPlay, which will record permanently, but only stores the last x minutes of footage (where x is a number you define), this saves space, is free and has little to no performance hindrances, I highly recommend it.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that Windows 10 has built-in screen recording. http://microsoft-news.com/how-to-record-your-screen-using-the-built-in-screen-recorder-on-windows-10/

Comment: Thanks for that addition, I don't have experience with Windows 10.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre, ShadowPlay is for nVidia only or suitable for Radeon?

Comment: @qpaycm Radeon has their own equivalent called RadeonPro which has a similar concept.

Comment: Useful.. but OP spexifically asks if the **game** has anything built in, so OS is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am looking on windows and nvidia cards. And my purpose is have a recording like DOTA2 and LoL which is replayed using game client. Yes, ShadowPlay is very good thing but all 3rd party tools seem to save recording in video format. Also Win10 feature apart for my use case seem good for all people who do not have nvidia or afford some 3rd party tools

Comment: @Timelord64 The Mac OS X version of the game _does_ have a built in video recorder.

Comment: I appreciate that the OS has the feature built in, but OP was specifically asking if the feature was available directly from the game, itself.